Why is my Google AdSense payment lower than expected by the amount of visitors?

Why is Google ad-sense not paying enough for ads by visitors or visit at site?
Google ad-sense not paying fair rate of ad revenue per almost 50k visits a year and 20k visitors to the site https://erikilonen.com?
Details: ad revenue only 2 dollars after a 50k visitors per a year 2024.
Link to the site Erik Ilonen

Google SiteKit gives wrong measures
